# How to force a different pointer on a bonded function

Tags: javascript

I am confused about how `bind` and `apply` work.

I know `bind` binds a pointer to a function and `apply` tell the function to run with the pointer given at the call time, so I did a little test and used the `apply` pointer but it didn't have any effects, it still uses the `bind` pointer.

How can I force the function to use a different pointer without bind a permanent new pointer?

Here is my test:

expected output:
**`this.test` is not a function**

```js
class A {
    test(){}
  
    printA() {
        this.test();
        console.log('A');
    }      
}

const dummy = function(func){
    func.apply(this, []);
};

const a = new A();
dummy(a.printA.bind(a));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` bound to a function reference with `.bind` cannot be overridden by passing a different `this` to `.apply`.

Think of `.bind` as working like this (but ignoring the ability of the real version to also attach extra preset function parameters):

```
function bind(fn, ctx) {
    return function(...args) {
        return fn.apply(ctx, args);
    }
}

let boundFunc = bind(myfunc, myctx);
boundFunc.apply(newctx, arg1, arg2);
```

You should be able to see that there's no way for `newctx` to be passed to `myfunc` via `boundFunc` because the innermost call to `.apply` in the closure inside `bind()` determines the passed context (i.e. the one supplied to `bind`).

Comment: I was to answer mostly the same thing than your edit. you were faster.